# Does the Preacher affect the Booty/Loot on the ship or in a den?

Tags: libertalia

In Libertalia, the character card [Preacher](http://boardgamegeek.com/image/1618012/libertalia?size=original) says:

> Discard all booty tiles but one.

Do you discard booty tiles from the ship, from your den, from every den, or some other variation?

An official FAQ, or designer response is what I am looking for.

Comment: It is unfortunate that the [French rules](http://fr.asmodee.com/ressources/ftpfr/Asmodee/libertalia_regle_FR.pdf) are no clearer nor the [French Priest card](http://fr.marabunta-games.com/?p=398), "défaussez toutes vos parts de butin sauf une." Neither

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules don't specify, but my interpretation agrees with [this](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/92999/libertalia-play-aid-by-d-a) player aid in that it's meant to be *your* booty tiles.

EDIT: A BGG post from [Stefan Brunell](http://boardgamegeek.com/user/Stefan%20B) the [American publisher](http://boardgamegeek.com/publisher/157) [here](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/9885147#9885147) confirms this.

> [Q2:] *The Preacher has a Dusk effect of "Remove all but one booty token." Is this referring to that day's booty, or your own inventory? Do the removed tokens go back to the bag or do they end up in your inventory?*
>
> Second: **Own inventory, to the bag.**

Comment: Publisher is definitive enough for my tastes.